# Acumatica AskExt not working

Tags: acumatica

hi I've been trying to replicate the AR Payment's LoadInvoice wherein it pops up a dialog box to filter invoices that will be added to tje Documents to Apply tab, but when I tried it on my own, I can't make it work. please help.

```
 [Serializable]
    public partial class LoadOptions : IBqlTable
    {
        #region Period
        public abstract class period : IBqlField { }
        private String _Period;

        [TranPeriodID(typeof(Today))]
        [PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Financial Period", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
        public String Period
        {
            get { return _Period; }
            set { _Period = value; }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public PXFilter<LoadOptions> loadOpts;

    public PXAction<ISAPAmmortization> loadDocuments;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Load Documents", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
    [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.Refresh)]
    public virtual IEnumerable LoadDocuments(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        if (loadOpts.AskExt() == WebDialogResult.OK)
        {
            LoadDocumentsProc(loadOpts.Current);
        }

        return adapter.Get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this custom on existing screen or add on custom.

If Custom on Existing screen i thing it's not possible.

But if u using add on custom, i think it's Possible.
On Pages u must add SmartPanel. and it's manual add on aspx. there is no wizard for add smartpanel on aspx.

Comment: this is a New Custom Graph that is not extended to any existing graph to acumatica..

okay gonna check on it manually adding the smartpanel